Issue while running multiple tests with Playwright Java and Cucumber
I'm trying to execute multiple tests using Playwright Java and Cucumber, but only one scenario executes successfully, others fails as couldn't find elements on Page.
Below the code of 2 classes: CucumberHook and LoginPOM. What am I doing wrong?
CucumberHook
public class CucumberHook {

    public static ThreadLocal<Playwright> playwright = new ThreadLocal<>();
    public static ThreadLocal<Browser> browser = new ThreadLocal<>();
    public static ThreadLocal<BrowserContext> browserContext = new ThreadLocal<>();
    public static ThreadLocal<Page> page = new ThreadLocal<>();


    @BeforeAll
    public static void beforeAll() {

        playwright.set(Playwright.create());
        browser.set(playwright.get().chromium().launch(new BrowserType.LaunchOptions()
                .setHeadless(false).setChannel("chrome")));

    }

    @Before
    public static void beforeScenario(Scenario scenario){

        browserContext.set(browser.get().newContext());
        page.set(browserContext.get().newPage());

        page.get().navigate("https://www.saucedemo.com/");

    }

LoginPOM
public class LoginPOM {

    private LoginPOM(){

    }

    private static LoginPOM INSTANCE;


    public static LoginPOM getInstance() {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE = new LoginPOM();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

     Page page = CucumberHook.page.get();


    {
        elementsMap.put("userNameInputField", page.locator("#user-name"));
        elementsMap.put("passwordInputField", page.locator("#password"));
        elementsMap.put("loginBtn", page.locator("#login-button"));
    }

    private Locator appLogo = page.locator(".app_logo");
    private Locator errorMsg = page.locator("//*[@data-test='error']");
}

